# convert if cycle to switch case

Tags: php

Hello I have the following If statement but obviously it is not going to work, my question is how to convert it to switch/case statement

```
 <?php if {
if($page == 'index') { echo 'images/home_background.jpg' }
if($page == 'cursos') { echo 'images/cursos_background.jpg' }
if($page == 'recetas') { echo 'images/recetas_background.jpg' }
if($page == 'sabias') { echo 'images/sabias_background.jpg' }
if($page == 'marcas') { echo 'images/marcas_background.jpg' }
if($page == 'nosotros') { echo 'images/nosotros_background.jpg' }
if($page == 'galeria') { echo 'images/galeria_background.jpg' }
if($page == 'contact') { echo 'images/contact_background.jpg' }
}
else
{
   echo 'images/home_background.jpg'
} ?>">
```

Comment: why won't this work? for help with syntax, please read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: It is not about the sytax, what I find it difficult is to recreate it with the switch case. since the switch you have different cases , how to make every case condition "if($page == 'index')" is the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
    $page_map = array(
        'index'    => 'home',
        'cursos'   => 'cursos',
        'recetas'  => 'recetas',
        'sabias'   => 'sabias',
        'marcas'   => 'marcas',
        'nosotros' => 'nosotros',
        'galeria'  => 'galeria',
        'contact'  => 'contact'
    );

    if (!isset($page_map[$page])) {
        $page = 'index';
    }

    echo 'images/' . $page_map[$page] . '_background.jpg';
?>
```

Comment: Very Elegant Solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
switch($page){
case 'index':
    echo 'images/home_background.jpg';
    break;
case 'cursos':
    echo 'images/cursos_background.jpg';
    break;
case 'recetas':
    echo 'images/recetas_background.jpg';
    break;
case 'sabias':
    echo 'images/sabias_background.jpg'
    break;
case 'marcas':
    echo 'images/marcas_background.jpg'
    break;
case 'nosotros':
    echo 'images/nosotros_background.jpg'
    break;
case 'galeria':
    echo 'images/galeria_background.jpg'
    break;
case 'contact':
    echo 'images/contact_background.jpg'
    break;
default:
    echo 'images/home_background.jpg'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if` can do what you want but you have syntax errors.
You can do it like this:

```
if($page == 'index') { echo 'images/home_background.jpg'; }
else if($page == 'cursos') { echo 'images/cursos_background.jpg'; }
else if($page == 'recetas') { echo 'images/recetas_background.jpg'; }
else if($page == 'sabias') { echo 'images/sabias_background.jpg'; }
else if($page == 'marcas') { echo 'images/marcas_background.jpg'; }
else if($page == 'nosotros') { echo 'images/nosotros_background.jpg'; }
else if($page == 'galeria') { echo 'images/galeria_background.jpg'; }
else if($page == 'contact') { echo 'images/contact_background.jpg'; }
else { echo 'images/home_background.jpg'; }
```

Comment: `elseif` can be one word in PHP. (What actually happens under the hood is a bit different, but it comes out the same.)